# PHP validate array with sub array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array with weekdays, by form submit I get additional data, but I want to validate this array, so if the array is empty a want to show a message, my problem there is always a sub-array called "games" and so is the main array never empty. How can I ignore them?

The "empty" array structure is like:

'`monday' = ['games' = [1, 2, 3, 'game_off']],`

[image: array dump]

Comment: Please post text and not pictures

Comment: So really, are you trying to verify that the games subarray is not empty? Or are there other things besides games that are supposed to be under the weekday name keys?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I want to ignore "games" array, becuase he is always available, if there is only "games" array this is error, is there is something new then it is correct

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the array and count the values for each day. Since there will always be one value for 'games', then look for counts < 2. If any are found, then that item only contains 'games' and your array is invalid.

```
$valid = true;
foreach ($array as $day => $values) {
    if (count($values) < 2) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This will verify that *every day* has something besides 'games'. If you need to verify that *any day* has something besides 'games', then the logic is the opposite.

```
$valid = false;
foreach ($array as $day => $values) {
    if (count($values) > 1) {
        $valid = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, at least two. 'games' + anything else would be at least two.

Comment: but not every array contains games I think.

Comment: The OP states _"there is always a sub-array called 'games'"_

Comment: @MarkoMackic that's how I interpreted it. Of course I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can walk into array and count them:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (is_array($item) && count(item) > 0){
        foreach ($item as $key => $subitem) {
            if ($key != 'games'){
               $count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

if ($count > 0){
  //your array is valid
}
```